# How to efficiently handle data with multiple filters in a shiny app

Tags: r, memory, shiny, data.table, reactive-programming

We have created a shiny application where either the user can upload a big dataset (RData file over 200MB) or they can pick one from us. Then there are three different tabs where the user can filter the data (tab for numerics, tab for categorics)

So currently I have 3 `reactive` functions to serve that purpose. But downside is that the object is kept three times in memory. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Please find a simplified example app below:
note: in this app you only see 1 filter per tab. normally its more like this:

```
My_Filtered_Data[Species %in% input$filter1 &
                   x %in% input$x &
                   y %in% input$y &
                   z %in% input$z] #etc.
```

I was looking at `reactiveValues` but couldn't really find how it works.
Reason I don't want to have it in 1 `reactive` is that everytime I change one of the filters on one of the sheets, the entire filtering process starts again and that is quite time consuming. I'd prefer to have one dataset that that gets updated with only the filter that is used at that time. That's the reason I included the different reactives

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
CustomHeader <- dashboardHeader(title='datatest')
iris<-iris

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    CustomHeader,
    ## Sidebar content
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("filter1 & Import", tabName = "filter1", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("filter2", tabName = "filter2", icon = icon("th")),
        menuItem("filter3", tabName = "filter3", icon = icon("th"))
      )
    ),
    ## Body content
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        # First tab content
        tabItem(tabName = "filter1",
                fluidRow(box(width = 3,
                             selectInput(inputId = 'filter1','filter1:species',choices = unique(iris$Species))))

        ),

        tabItem(tabName = "filter2",
                fluidRow(box(width = 3,
                             sliderInput(inputId = 'filter2','filter2:Max.Sepal.Length',min = 0,max = 10,value = 10)
                                         ))

        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "filter3",
                fluidRow(box(width = 3,
                             sliderInput(inputId = 'filter3','filter3:Min.Sepal.Width',min = 0,max = 10,value = 0)
                             ),
                         box(width=9,dataTableOutput('mydata')))

        )
        )
      )
    )

}
server <- function(input, output) {
  My_Uploaded_Data <- reactive({
    My_Uploaded_Data<-data.table(iris)
    My_Uploaded_Data
  })

  My_Filtered_Data <- reactive({
    My_Filtered_Data<-My_Uploaded_Data()
    My_Filtered_Data[Species %in% input$filter1]
  })

  My_Filtered_Data2 <- reactive({
    My_Filtered_Data2<-My_Filtered_Data()
    My_Filtered_Data2[Sepal.Length < input$filter2]
  })  

  My_Filtered_Data3 <- reactive({
    My_Filtered_Data3<-My_Filtered_Data2()
    My_Filtered_Data3[Sepal.Width > input$filter3]
  })  
  output$mydata<-renderDataTable({
    My_Filtered_Data3()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I was hoping something like tthis would work in `reactiveValues`

```
 react_vals <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  observe(react_vals$data <- MyLoadedData())
  observe(react_vals$data <- react_vals$data[Species %in% input$filter1])
  observe(react_vals$data <- react_vals$data[Sepal.Length < input$filter2])
  observe(react_vals$data <- react_vals$data[Sepal.Width > input$filter3])
```

**EDIT:** I also would like to include bookmarks: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html and it seems you need `reactiveValues` for that. So another reason for me to move away from all these `reactives`/`eventReactive`

Comment: Interesting problem. The issue with your reactiveValues approach is that if you apply a filter on filter1, and then remove that filter again, the filter would still apply, since the reactiveVal doesn't contain the filtered records anymore. So you'd have to create another reactiveVal that contains the filters, and an observer to check if a filter is broadened or limited. In the second case all filters should be applied again to the original dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of storing datasets in the reactive variables, just store the rows which qualify. That way, each reactive value is only replaced when it's filter changes; they aren't linked together. The output just uses the rows which pass all filters.

At the top of the program, change `iris` to a `data.table`:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
CustomHeader <- dashboardHeader(title = 'datatest')
iris <- iris
setDT(iris)  # Added
```

Then use this for the server logic:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  filter1_rows <- reactive({
    iris[Species %in% input$filter1,   which = TRUE]
  })
  filter2_rows <- reactive({
    iris[Sepal.Length < input$filter2, which = TRUE]
  })
  filter3_rows <- reactive({
    iris[Sepal.Width > input$filter3,  which = TRUE]
  })
  output$mydata <- renderDataTable({
    final_rows <- intersect(filter1_rows(), filter2_rows())
    final_rows <- intersect(final_rows,     filter3_rows())
    iris[final_rows]
  })
}
```

This uses the often-overlooked `which` argument for `data.table[...]`, which means only the row numbers of the subsetted table should be returned.

Comment: Fyi, after `setDT`, you can do `setindex(iris, Species); setindex(iris, Sepal.Length); setindex(iris, Sepal.Width)` which should speed things up, at least with larger tables.

Comment: This works great on this dataset. Let me try it out on the large data I use and I'll mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem has nothing to do with shiny and/or reactive programming. It's a "classic time vs memory" situation. Basically speaking you have only two options: Store "partially" filtered objects or not.

If you do store them, you use a lot of memory but can return the object instantly. If not, you need only store the original object but you have to filter it everytime again. There is nothing in between. You just cannot create an object that is different from the original (i.e. filtered) but takes no additional memory, not even with `reactiveValues`.

Of course you can do tradeoffs, e.g. creating an intermediate object for the first filter and computing the second and the third filter on-the-fly, but that does not change the underlying problem.

Comment: So if what you are saying is true, how would you handle this in reactiveValues in the most optimal way?

Comment: My point is that there is no optimal way. You can choose if you want to spend more memory or more time. You cannot have fast response time and low memory profile simultaneosly. It doesn't matter if you use `reactiveValues` or not. In fact, for your example "normal" `reactive`s are just fine.

Comment: But that interferes with for example the bookmark option. I'm also not sure how to implement such a procedure as I now have with reactives in ``reactiveValues``. No sure if it's feasible

Comment: I don't see how that interferes? Bookmarking application state is an entirely different topic as efficient filtering. Anyway, you will not be able to encode a 200MB file into a bookmark (which would then be 200MB big). You can only either save just the filter values or save the state somewhere on the server. Saving the filter values in a `reactiveValues` can be done exactly like in your example.

Comment: There's also another possibility, I think. Since the OP is filtering with equality conditions, a join could be used `DT[input, on=join_cols, nomatch=0]` and these joins can be faster by either setting keys equal to the join_cols if they're always the same or by setting (what the package calls) indices for many possible sets of join_cols. Indices have some time cost but can be done before any query is made; they have very little memory cost. I don't know shiny, so I can't answer this question, though.